# sklearn normalize() produces every value as 1

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, normalization

I'm trying to normalize a single feature to [0, 1], but the result I'm getting back is all float values of 1 and is clearly wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

test = pd.DataFrame(data=[7, 6, 5, 2, 9, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5], columns=['data'])
normalize(test['data'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

This produces the following output:

```
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])
```

I thought this might be an int to float datatype issue so I tried casting to float first, `normalize(test['data'].astype(float).values.reshape(-1, 1))`, but this gives the same result.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the default `axis` is 1.

Set `axis = 0`:

```
normalize(test['data'].values.reshape(-1, 1), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.32998316],
       [0.28284271],
       [0.23570226],
       [0.0942809 ],
       [0.42426407],
       [0.42426407],
       [0.32998316],
       [0.37712362],
       [0.28284271],
       [0.23570226]])
```

Comment: Very odd - usually `axis=1` corresponds to a column, ie a feature in my mind, so I assumed that default was fine.  I guess when I use `reshape` to meet `sklearn`'s 2D array requirement, it's now being viewed as a "row"/sample rather than a column/feature.

Comment: @JulianDrago Because its `l2` norm by default. Try `norm='max'` :)

Answer (score 2):

I feel like we can use

```
(test.data-test.data.min())/np.ptp(test.data.values)
Out[136]: 
0    0.714286
1    0.571429
2    0.428571
3    0.000000
4    1.000000
5    1.000000
6    0.714286
7    0.857143
8    0.571429
9    0.428571
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Numerically this looks right so +1, though I'm interested in the `sklearn`-based solution.